# Closed form for $f(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{it^{x}}dt$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

> Let $x>1$ and $f(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{it^{x}}dt$. Does this integral have a closed form ?

Fist point, the integral converges. Indeed let $u=e^{it^{x}}$ and $v=\frac{-i}{x}t^{1-x}$ we have by integration by parts $$\lim_{T\rightarrow+\infty}\int_0^T=\int_0^1 e^{it^x}dt+\frac{i}{x}e^i+\frac{1-x}{x}\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{e^{it^x}}{t^x}dt$$ One can also prove that $f(x)\sim_{+\infty}1.$

Comment: $\dfrac{\exp(i\pi/2x)\Gamma(1/x)}x$ (using Maple).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf This isn't really a satisfactory answer given that $\Gamma$ is defined by
$$\Gamma(t) := \int_0^{\infty}x^{t-1}\mathrm{e}^{-x}~\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @FlybyNight that's why I only wrote a comment, and not an answer… `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Comments are to ask for more information or to suggest improvement. It's neither a satisfactory answer, nor an appropriate comment... :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For integral
$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{it^{x}}dt$$

We first change variable from $t$ to $v=-i t^x$ so that $t=v^{1/x}i^{1/x}$ and $dt=i^{1/x}(1/x)v^{-1+1/x}dv$.

The integral now becomes

$$f(x)=i^{1/x}(1/x)\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-v}v^{-1+1/x}dv......(1)$$

Mathematica 7.0 gives:

$$f(x)=(1/x)\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{2x}\right)\Gamma(1/x)$$

The definition of the $\Gamma(z)$ function is given by:

$$\Gamma(t)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-v}v^{t-1}dv......(2)$$

Comparison of (1) against (2) leads to the same result:

$$f(x)=(1/x)i^{1/x}\Gamma(1/x)=(1/x)\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{2x}\right)\Gamma(1/x)......(3)$$

Comment: first change variable from $t$ to $v=t^x$, then integrate it.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Don't try to understand why downvotes while you give a good answer. I gave up myself. So, $+1$ for you. Cheers :)

Comment: @mike Just mishandling, it was a +1 not -1.

Comment: @Mike: Why not incorporate your comment to your own answer into the answer? :)

Comment: @mike The definition of $\Gamma$ is
$$\Gamma(t) := \int_0^{\infty} x^{t-1}\mathrm{e}^{-x}~\mathrm{d}x$$ An answer involving $\Gamma$ is no closer to closed form expression than the OP itself.

Comment: @FlybyNight Well, it is a difference of taste then.  In my opinion, we know so much about the $\Gamma$ function (its poles, zeros, asymptotic behavior etc), it should count as a closed-form solution. The original integral expression will not give you such information.

Comment: @mike No, it's a matter of definition. Wikipedia: "*Unlike the broader analytic expressions, the closed-form expressions do not include infinite series or continued fractions; neither includes integrals or limits*".

Comment: @FlybyNight Thanks for the heads up. I think that it is called analytic expression then.  From Wikipedia, "In mathematics, an expression is said to be a closed-form expression if it can be expressed analytically in terms of a finite number of certain "well-known" functions. Typically, these well-known functions are defined to be elementary functions—constants, one variable x, elementary operations of arithmetic (+ − × ÷), nth roots, exponent and logarithm (which thus also include trigonometric functions and inverse trigonometric functions). "

Comment: @mike No, they're not even analytic, as my original quote says. Analytic expressions allow infinite series and (infinite) continued fractions, provided that they converge. Integrals are not included. The quote you posted does not mention integrals whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

@FlybyNight

I just need the space in the answer to show that Gamma function as well as special functions like Bessel functions, are considered as analytic expression. Please do not give me the down vote if you do not agree with me.

Thanks-
mike

Here is from Wikipedia:

In mathematics, an analytical expression (or expression in analytical form) is a mathematical expression constructed using well-known operations that lend themselves readily to calculation. As is true for closed-form expressions, the set of well-known functions allowed can vary according to context but always includes the basic arithmetic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division), exponentiantion to a real exponent (which includes extraction of the nth root), logarithms, and trigonometric functions.
However, the class of expressions considered to be analytical expressions tends to be wider than that for closed-form expressions. In particular, special functions such as the Bessel functions and the gamma function are usually allowed, and often so are infinite series and continued fractions. On the other hand, limits in general, and integrals in particular, are typically excluded.